# Regex to match all subpaths except a list but not the base path

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match all subpaths under a given path with a handful of exceptions.

**The regex:**

`^\/my-page\/(?!.*foo|bar|baz).*`

**Expected behavior:**

`/my-page/thing1` - match!

`/my-page/another-thing` - match!

`/my-page/foo` - no match

`/my-page/bar` - no match

`/my-page/baz` - no match

This works as expected ✅

**The problem:**

The base path is *also* matched:

`/my-page/` - match... **but I don't want this to match**. ❌

How can I adjust the regex expression to prevent `/my-page/` from matching also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^\/my-page\/(?!.*(?:foo|bar|baz)).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t7tKWl/1).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `\/my-page\/` - `/my-page/` string
- `(?!.*(?:foo|bar|baz))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `foo`, `bar` or `baz` after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.